# TDD and parameter validation Javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, parameters, tdd, dry

How to keep your code DRY and follow TDD principles? Just imagine 2 functions with the same parameter called one after the other. Only checking/validating in the first function will obviously lead to performance gains but how do you individually test the functions?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what Donald Knuth [wrote](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization):

> Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying
>   about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these
>   attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when
>   debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small
>   efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the
>   root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that
>   critical 3%.

Is that validation really critical from performance perspective? If it is not it does not make sense to optimize. You will spend more time and effort dealing with errors caused by the lack of the validation.

In the very rare case that validation is really performance critical (or complex) you move it out and just check that functions do call the validator. And the validator can cache the result of the validation to not have a performance hit. And of cause you have tests for validator logic logic and for caching logic which is not part of the initial functions logic.